# Is there any way to launch URL in Google Chrome in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am using launch_url plugin to launch url, but its launching it on default Browser like Safari in IOS case, I wanted to know Is there any way to launch it on Google Chrome Only ?

```
if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url, forceSafariVC: false);
} else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
}
```